# How to access config.yml file in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I have some private credentials. Is there a way to access the credentials in the config.yml file in Shopify?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such file in Shopify.

This file is for local development only used with Themekit(or Slate), not for the production theme.

Comment: That isn't completely correct. The confiigyml is a general file for "configuration". It can be set also at deploy server that will pick up the eviromental variable for prodaction. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

The config.yml file is generated using following command.
It is a file that store "setting" for the theme and can be of "development", "production" and so on.

```
theme get --password=[your-password] --store="[your-store.myshopify.com]" --themeid=[your-theme-id]
```

theme-id is obtained by running the following

```
theme get --list --password=[your-password] --store="[your- 
store.myshopify.com]"
```

once created it, you can include credential following best practice using eviromental variable for each "environment" as from [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/tools/theme-kit/configuration-reference)